# Algorithm to check whether a certain hour falls into a given time period

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

Assume I've got a start and stop hour in which some processing should take place:

Start 20:00
End 07:00

Now what is the best algorithm to check if a certain DateTime hour value falls within this range? Thanks in advance!

Please note that the start and end times mentioned above indicate that we are dealing with an "overnight-job". Meaning that the period to be checked starts at 20:00 in the evening and ends at 07:00 on the following morning.

Comment: How do you know that End is only 1 day ahead? And what about if End is say 22:00. Is that same day as Start or is that the next day at 10pm?

Comment: Even just overnight can span end-of-month and end-of-year boundaries.

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question - so many of the answers to the original question are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

Assume you only have the time and not the date.

```
if end_time >= start_time:
    return start_time <= current_time <= end_time
else:
    return start_time <= current_time or current_time <= end_time
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure it is in the same day

you also do not seem to care for seconds

Transform everything in minutes

```
startminute = 20 * 60 + 0
endminute = 7 * 60 + 0
eventminute = x * 60 + y // with event having the form xx:yy
return startminute < eventminute && eventminute < endminute
```

Another option would be to get the 3 times in DateTime format

```
DateTime start, end, event

return (start < event && event < end);
```

Comment: The shown example in my post indicates, that this is an "overnight" job (starting today at 20:00 and ending tomorrow at 07:00 in the morning). So I guess your solution won't work well. Thanks anyway! (btw, I've updated the question to clarify)

Comment: But, your edit was after this answer - so withdrawing the question and re-asking would be better

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a start, end and now DateTime, you could use

```
bool within = start.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours && 
              now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= end.TimeOfDay.TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how to do it in C#, I'd go with converting start and end time to a timestamp and then do a simple `if (end time >= given time AND start time <= given time)` comparison. Maybe that'll get you started or give you a hint what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I think c# supports [greater than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_greaterthan(VS.71).aspx)/[less than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthan(VS.71).aspx) operators for DateTime variables, so just say

```
if ((beginDateTime<myDateTime)&&(myDateTime<endDateTime))
{
    ...
}
```

Also greater than or equal to and less than or equal to are supported.

Answer (score 0):

if ALL you have are those values for start and stop, don't you have an empty set?

Ignore the obvious assumption - start day X, end day X + Y.

[edit]
since the question has been edited, so shall be the answer....

for start time, end time and 'test' time get the number of milliseconds from the epoch
 *(define that any way you would like)* 
and then check to see if test is >= start and <= end 
[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

With an *overnight* window, I don't think there's anything particularly clever to be done except to directly check your `DateTime`'s `TimeOfDay` against the boundaries:

```
using System;

namespace Question2355777
{
    class Program
    {    
        private static bool IsInOvernightWindow(
            DateTime dateTimeUnderTest, 
            TimeSpan morningEnd, 
            TimeSpan eveningStart)
        {
            TimeSpan timeOfDay = dateTimeUnderTest.TimeOfDay;
            return timeOfDay <= morningEnd || timeOfDay >= eveningStart;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSpan eveningStart = TimeSpan.FromHours(20);
            TimeSpan morningEnd = TimeSpan.FromHours(7);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
                DateTime.Today.AddHours(3),
                IsInOvernightWindow(
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(3), 
                    morningEnd, 
                    eveningStart));

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
                DateTime.Today.AddHours(12),
                IsInOvernightWindow(
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(12), 
                    morningEnd, 
                    eveningStart));

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
                DateTime.Today.AddHours(21),
                IsInOvernightWindow(
                    DateTime.Today.AddHours(21), 
                    morningEnd, 
                    eveningStart));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

produces

```
01/03/2010 03:00:00 True
01/03/2010 12:00:00 False
01/03/2010 21:00:00 True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// initializing with some sample values
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.FromHours(20);
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.FromHours(7);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

return start<end
    ? start <= now.TotalHours && now.TotalHours <= end
    : start <= now.TotalHours || now.TotalHours <= end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the TimeOfDay method:

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(0,0,0,20,0,0);
DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(0,0,0,7,0,0);

if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < dtEnd.TimeOfDay || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > dtStart.TimeOfDay)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for basic cases. Such as the time is 17:00, and you want to run between 15:00 and 16:00. In that case your if should be false, but since you or the values your if is true (17 is greater than the start)

Answer (score 0):

Count all the times in units of minutes beginning from the start day.

```
struct DateTime {
  uint_8 hour_;
  uint_8 minute_;
};

bool
isTimeWithin( DateTime start, DataTime stop, DateTime query ) {

  // The following times are counted from the beginning of start day

  uint_16 startInMins = (60 * start.hour_ + start.minute_);

  // Added 24*60 since "stop" is always "overnight" from "start"
  uint_16 stopInMins = 24 * 60 + (60 * stop.hour_ + stop.minute_); 

  // The ternary operator checks whether "query" is in the same day as
  // "start" or the next day
  uint_16 queryInMins = (query.hour_ < start.hour_ ? 24 * 60 : 0 ) + 
                           (60 * query.hour_ + query.minute_); 

  return ((startInMins <= queryInMins) && (queryInMins <= stopInMins));

}
```

EDIT: Improved Formatting.